# My react-native-app freezes when i use while loop

Tags: javascript, react-native, while-loop, date-fns, react-native-calendars

This component displays calendar to the patients so that they can select the appointment day from the appointment days of doctor. Doctor appointment days are fetched from api. What i am trying to achieve is to disable all other weekdays days in the calendar except the doctor appointment days so that patients can only press one of the appointment days. i am using react-native-calendars library and date-fns-library for dates. However my app is freezing once while loop is being defined. What am i doing wrong here ? Also is there a better way of doing what i am trying to achieve?

```
import { View } from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Calendar, CalendarProps } from "react-native-calendars";
import startOfMonth from "date-fns/startOfMonth";
import endOfMonth from "date-fns/endOfMonth";
import isBefore from "date-fns/isBefore";
import addDays from "date-fns/addDays";
import format from "date-fns/format";
import setDay from "date-fns/setDay";
import api from "../../config/api";
import Layout from "../UI/Layout";
import RegularText from "../UI/Text/RegularText";
import { useAppSelector } from "../../store/hooks";
import { useRoute } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { AppointmentDaysScreenRouteProp } from "../../@types/navigation";

const weekdays = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"] as const;

type weekday = typeof weekdays[number];

const CalendarComponent = () => {
  const language = useAppSelector((state) => state.language.selected);
  const [markedDates, setMarkedDates] = useState<CalendarProps["markedDates"]>(
    {}
  );
  const [disabledledWeekdays, setDisbaledWeekdays] = useState<number[]>([]);
  const route = useRoute<AppointmentDaysScreenRouteProp>();

  const { doctorId } = route.params;

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  let text = {
    loading: "...Please wait",
  };

  if (language === "اردو") {
    text = {
      loading: "...لوڈ ہو رہا ہے",
    };
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const res = await api.get<{ appointmentDays: weekday[] }>(
          `/appointments/appointmentDays/doctorId/${doctorId}`
        );

        const { appointmentDays } = res.data;
        const disabledDays = weekdays
          .filter((item) => !appointmentDays.includes(item))
          .map((item) => weekdays.indexOf(item));

        const now = new Date();

        getDisabledDays(now.getMonth(), now.getFullYear(), disabledDays);

        setDisbaledWeekdays(disabledDays);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    })();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  const getDisabledDays = (
    month: number,
    year: number,
    daysIndexes: number[]
  ) => {
    const now = new Date();

    now.setFullYear(year, month);

    const pivot = startOfMonth(now);
    const end = endOfMonth(now);
    const dates: CalendarProps["markedDates"] = {};

    const disabled = { disabled: true, disableTouchEvent: true };
    //THIS WHILE LOOP IS FREEZING MY APP
    //IF I REMOVE THIS LOOP APP WORKS FINE
    while (isBefore(pivot, end)) {
      daysIndexes.forEach((day) => {
        const copy = setDay(new Date(pivot), day);
        dates[format(copy, "yyyy-MM-dd")] = disabled;
      });
      addDays(pivot, 7);
    }
    setMarkedDates(dates);
    return dates;
  };

  return (
    <Layout>
      <View>
        {loading ? (
          <RegularText>{text.loading}</RegularText>
        ) : (
          <Calendar
            theme={{
              textSectionTitleDisabledColor: "#d9e1e8",
            }}
            markedDates={markedDates}
            onDayPress={(day) => {
              console.log("dosomething with ", day);
            }}
            firstDay={1}
            enableSwipeMonths={true}
            disabledDaysIndexes={disabledledWeekdays}
             onMonthChange={(date) => {
               getDisabledDays(date.month - 1, date.year, disabledledWeekdays);
             }}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default CalendarComponent;
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation, I'm it seems that `addDays(date, amount)` is returning a new date and not modifying the value of `pivot`. Try doing `pivot = addDays(pivot, 7)`

Comment: @DrZoo Thanks dude. You are awesome. you can post your comment as answer and i will accept it. don't know i missed this.

Comment: Sometimes a fresh set of eyes spot the easy errors. I've glossed over things like that pleeeeeeeeeenty of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/addDays), I'm it seems that `addDays(date, amount`) is returning a new date and not modifying the value of `pivot`. Try doing `pivot = addDays(pivot, 7)`